# Scalable alternative to dozens of joins to the same table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a base table with primary key `BaseTableID` and an events table that represents multiple events for a single record in the base table, i.e.

```
BaseTableID | EventCode | EventSequenceNumber
------------|-----------|--------------------
1           | A123      | 1
1           | A557      | 2
1           | 45AB      | 3
1           | 0987      | 4
...
1           | SD12      | 70
2           | Z902      | 1
2           | D92C      | 2
... etc ...
```

I need to denormalize this in order to provide a flat file in the format:

```
BaseTableID | Event01 | Event02 | Event03 | ... | Event70
------------|---------|---------|---------|-----|---------
1           | A123    | A557    | 45AB    | ... | SD12
2           | Z902    | D92C    |
... etc ...
```

I *can* currently achieve this with the query

```sql
select BaseTable.BaseTableID,
       Event01 = Event01.EventCode,
       Event02 = Event02.EventCode,
       Event03 = Event03.EventCode,
       Event04 = Event04.EventCode,
       ...
from BaseTable

left join Events Event01
on BaseTable.BaseTableID = Event01.BaseTableID
and Event01.EventSequenceNumber = 1

left join Events Event02
on BaseTable.BaseTableID = Event02.BaseTableID
and Event02.EventSequenceNumber = 2

left join Events Event03
on BaseTable.BaseTableID = Event03.BaseTableID
and Event03.EventSequenceNumber = 3

left join Events Event04
on BaseTable.BaseTableID = Event04.BaseTableID
and Event04.EventSequenceNumber = 4

... etc...
```

Which *works*, but scales horribly and the number of joins / columns is entirely dependent on `select max(EventSequenceNumber) from Events`, which could (and is likely to) change over time. Imagine the nightmare situation when one base table record ends up with hundreds of events. I don't want to copy-paste hundreds of joins!

(Worth noting - the format of required output is well outside my control. I can't change that to something more sensible)

**There must be a better way**. Is there?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query to get a direction.

Answer (score 0):

This will works..

```
CREATE  TABLE temp(BaseTableID INT, EventCode VARCHAR(10), EventSequenceNumber INT)
DECLARE @EventSequenceNumber VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(MAX)

INSERT INTO temp(BaseTableID,EventCode,EventSequenceNumber)
SELECT 1  ,' A123', 1 UNION
SELECT 1  ,' A557 ', 2 UNION
SELECT 1 ,'  45AB  ', 3 UNION
SELECT 2  ,' 0987', 4

SELECT @EventSequenceNumber= ISNULL(@EventSequenceNumber+',','')+'Event'+
CAST(EventSequenceNumber AS VARCHAR) FROM temp ORDER BY EventSequenceNumber


SET @Query='SELECT BaseTableID,'+@EventSequenceNumber+' FROM (SELECT BaseTableID,EventCode,
''Event''+CAST(EventSequenceNumber AS VARCHAR)AS EventSequenceNumber
FROM temp)pvt PIVOT 
(MAX(EventCode) FOR EventSequenceNumber IN ('+@EventSequenceNumber+
'))dst'

execute(@Query)
DROP TABLE temp
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up pivoting as follows. It's not 100% scalable (will need manually adjusting if events go over 100), but for the required purposes, strikes a usable balance without needing to use dynamic SQL and strings.

```
with EventsPivot as (
    select
        BaseTableID,
        Event01 = [01], Event02 = [02], Event03 = [03], Event04 = [04], Event05 = [05], 
        Event06 = [06], Event07 = [07], Event08 = [08], Event09 = [09], Event10 = [10], 
        Event11 = [11], Event12 = [12], Event13 = [13], Event14 = [14], Event15 = [15], 
        Event16 = [16], Event17 = [17], Event18 = [18], Event19 = [19], Event20 = [20]
    from (
        select BaseTableID, EventSequenceNumber, EventCode
        from Events
    ) a
    pivot (
        max(EventCode) for EventSequenceNumber in (
            [01], [02], [03], [04], [05], [06], [07], [08], [09], [10],
            [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20]
        )
    ) p
)
select
    BaseTableID,
    Event01 = EventsPivot.Event01,
    Event02 = EventsPivot.Event01,
    Event03 = EventsPivot.Event01,
    ...
from BaseTable

left join EventsPivot
on BaseTable.BaseTableID = EventsPivot.BaseTableID
```

You can achieve a truly scalable version with dynamic SQL, at a readability/maintainability cost (adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10404455/2061621, go upvote that if it's useful):

```
-- creates '[01],[02],[03]' etc, though order not guaranteed
declare @shortCols as nvarchar(max) =
    stuff((
        select distinct Value = ',' + quotename(right('0' + cast(EventSequenceNumber as varchar), 2))
        from Events
        order by Value
        for xml path(''), 
        type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')

-- creates 'Event01 = EventsPivot.[01],Event02 = EventsPivot.[02],Event03 = EventsPivot.[03]' etc, though order not guaranteed
declare @longCols as nvarchar(max) =
    stuff((
        select distinct Value = ',' + quotename('Event' + right('0' + cast(EventSequenceNumber as varchar), 2)) + ' = ' + quotename(right('0' + cast(EventSequenceNumber as varchar), 2))
        from Events
        order by Value
        for xml path(''), 
        type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')

exec('
    with EventsPivot as (
        select
            BaseTableID,
            ' + @shortCols + '
        from (
            select BaseTableID, EventSequenceNumber, EventCode
            from Events
        ) a
        pivot (
            max(EventCode) for EventSequenceNumber in (
                ' + @shortCols + '
            )
        ) p
    )
    select
        BaseTable.BaseTableID,
        ' + @longCols + '
    from BaseTable
    left join EventsPivot
    on BaseTable.BaseTableID = EventsPivot.BaseTableID
')
```